# How can I switch to root on Ubuntu? NO sudo

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, root, su

Yes, I know sudo is a better way but this is a particular case where **sudo isn't an option**.
On most Unix/Linux distributions this works by adding a user to a group (wheel, root) but I can't figure out how does it work on Ubuntu.
All I get when I try to "su" is `su: Permission denied`
Note: root was enabled (passwd root)

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: cross site duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login You might also need to run `sudo passwd -u root`

Comment: OP states sudo is not an option

Answer (score 0):

Try logging in as u: root p: toor or root. If you can't, try

1. restart,
2. Once the GRUB page appears, quickly select the “*Advanced options for GNU/Linux” option by pressing the down arrow key and Enter button.
3. Press e to edit commands, You need to modify it or change it from “read-only” mode to “read-write” mode. Find the line beginning with “Linux.” After, look for “ro,” and change it “rw.” Add init=/bin/bash at the end of the line.
4. Press F10. This will display a screen with a prompt.
5. Mount your root filesystem in read-write mode: `mount -n -o remount,rw /`
6. You can now reset your lost root password by using the following command: `passwd root` Alternatively, you can change the password of the super user with the command: `passwd username`. When you are done, type `exec /sbin/init`. Now restart and login as root with the password you gave to root account.

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clean, but I didn't lose my password :-)
I need to switch to root from a none root user.

Comment: try logging in as root and the password you gave to the root account

Answer (score 0):

By updating /etc/pam.d/su as follows I was able to fix the issue:

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth        sufficient    pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
auth        sufficient    pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
auth        required    pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth        substack    system-auth
auth        include        postlogin
#account        sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
#account        include        system-auth
password    include        system-auth
#session        include        system-auth
#session        include        postlogin
session        optional    pam_xauth.so
```

Answer (score -2):

If I get it, you typed "su" you got permission denied. You need "sudo su" instead

Comment: sudo is not an option - please see my original post for details